# How to Send M-SEARCH Query with Java

Tags: java, networking, ssdp

I have a Roku device on my network and I want to be able to discover it programically. The [official Roku documentation](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+Guide) says:

> There is a standard SSDP multicast address and port
>   (239.255.255.250:1900) that is used for local network communication.
>   The Roku responds to M-SEARCH queries on this ip address and port.
>
> In order to query for the roku ip address, your program can send the
>   following request using the http protocol to 239.255.255.250 port
>   1900:

They provide an example using netcat and they say that wireshark can be used to find the result. They also say:

> The External Control Protocol enables the Roku to be controlled via
>   the network. The External Control Service is discoverable via SSDP
>   (Simple Service Discovery Protocol). The service is a simple RESTful
>   API **that can be accessed by programs in virtually any programming
>   environment.**

I have a java program that controls my Roku given its IP Address, and I would like to implement a function that discovers it on the network using this SSDP.

How do I send an M-SEARCH query with java? I have absolutely no conception of how to do this. Is it like an get/post request? If somebody could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a java solution:

```
/* multicast SSDP M-SEARCH example for 
 * finding the IP Address of a Roku
 * device. For more info go to: 
 * http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+Guide 
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class msearchSSDPRequest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        /* create byte arrays to hold our send and response data */
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

        /* our M-SEARCH data as a byte array */
        String MSEARCH = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\nHost: 239.255.255.250:1900\nMan: \"ssdp:discover\"\nST: roku:ecp\n"; 
        sendData = MSEARCH.getBytes();

        /* create a packet from our data destined for 239.255.255.250:1900 */
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, InetAddress.getByName("239.255.255.250"), 1900);

        /* send packet to the socket we're creating */
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

        /* recieve response and store in our receivePacket */
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);

        /* get the response as a string */
        String response = new String(receivePacket.getData());

        /* print the response */
        System.out.println(response);

        /* close the socket */
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wasn't it necessary to add a second \n in the end of the MSEARCH string? It was in my case.

Comment: @dr.doom Oh interesting, it works fine for me without the second newline, but it's good to know that in some cases it may be required

Comment: well, according to the http spec, the Request (section 5) and Response (section 6) messages use the generic message format of RFC 822 [9] for transferring entities (the payload of the message). Both types of message consist of a start-line, zero or more header fields (also known as "headers"), an empty line (i.e., a line with nothing preceding the CRLF) indicating the end of the header fields, and possibly a message-body. So the empty line is mandatory and if not a body is present it marks the end of the message...

Comment: I had to add "MX: 10" (without quotes) to the MSEARCH String value for it to work in macOS Sierra

Comment: @ObjSal Oh interesting! You had to prepend with that? On its own line or anything?

Comment: @JohnDorian I added the MX delay within the string in a new line after the Host IP address

Comment: For other service such as DIAL, you need to do `String MSEARCH = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\nMX: 5\nHost: 239.255.255.250:1900\nMan: \"ssdp:discover\"\nST: urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1\n\n";`, which `MX: n` must appear at least after`HTTP/1.1`, and trailing extra `\n` is required. Change `\n` to `\r\n` is optional.

Comment: I got Below Error

java.io.IOException: sendto failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:603)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:571)
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:124)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:721)